# Port vs Subdomain understanding on Web Application running on Production Server

Tags: asp.net-core, web-deployment, production-environment

Following a Pluralsight tutorial I built 3 Asp.Net Core projects within a Solution and all 3 of them run on different ports through which they also communicate with each other:

`Project1/localhost:28851`,
`Project2/localhost:59418` and
`Project3/localhost:33918`

How does the port thing really work on production? Does this mean I will have to buy subdomains for each port or they can all run within a single domain.

I would like to know how it works in details, if possible.

Thank you

Comment: Use a simple google search about ports and find Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking) I think this could help you understanding ports and domains.

Comment: @HeinzSchilling thanks for your response and I apologize for having mislead you by asking the wrong question. When I asked about a detailed explanation I was hoping for more of a dummy language explanation (the minimum knowledge required to deploy 3 projects using 3 different ports in a live server), simply referring to my situation. Every time I googled I ended up in terminologies I didn't understand. Therefore, if there is a simpler way of understanding what I need to know without having to study ports would be much appreciated.

Comment: "I will have to buy subdomains"? Why? If you do own a domain, then all subdomains can be free.

Comment: @LexLi What I'm interested to know is how are localhost ports addressed in the domain world/production servers

Comment: Those `localhost` site bindings are simply what VS/you chose to host the web apps on IIS Express. When moving to IIS/production, you can remap them to other site bindings, https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/24/understanding-iis-bindings-websites-virtual-directories-and-lastly-application-pools/

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, I checked the link, seems like there is a lot of information that could be helpful, I will read the article carefully as soon as I get a chance. Thanks again.